# CloudApp uploaded file with Qt not showing even when response code is correct

Tags: qt

I'm having this issue when trying to upload a file to CloudApp (getcloudapp.com).

After posting the file, and tracking the upload progress, I see the file is uploaded completely, and I'm getting the *303 See Other* response code, as expected, like show in the [API Documentation](https://github.com/cloudapp/api/blob/master/upload-file.md). I'm also getting the Location header with the redirection target URL, however, I'm not seeing the file under my files in my account.

Qt doesn't follow redirections, so you have to do it by hand, if I try to get the URL I got in the Location header from the response, I'm getting redirected again.
So, for example, I post the file, I see in debug messages the *sentBytes* and the *totalBytes* are 9728 and 9728, respectively, which shows the upload has been completed.
The response code is *303*, and the response body (got trhough reply->readAll() method) is *See Other*, the *Location* header in the response has something like this:

`http://my.cl.ly/items/s3?bucket=f.cl.ly&key=items0.0000002V1n29090S1u2f3j0t230.000000arch-tux.png&etag=%22b3e0682a5bdaa51eb2a342a4ea77aa0f%22`

When I try to get that URL, I'm getting a *302* response code with this body:

`<html><body>You are being <a href="http://my.cl.ly/">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

So, no errors, but no uploaded file either.
I've played with the field names, policy encryption and a few more things, but when changing any of them, I'm getting explicit errors indicating what's wrong, that's why I assume the post is OK.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Update with the code posting the file**

`
    QJsonParseError error;
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &error);
    QJsonObject response = document.object();

```
QJsonObject params = response.take("params").toObject();
QHttpPart AWSKey;
QHttpPart key;
QHttpPart policy;
QHttpPart signature;
QHttpPart successRedirect;
QHttpPart acl;
QHttpPart filePart;
QMimeDatabase mime;

QUrl url(response.take("url").toString());
QHttpMultiPart *fileData = new QHttpMultiPart(this);
QCloudFileUploadThread *thread = uploaders.take(uploaders.keys().at(0));

AWSKey.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"AWSAccessKeyId\""));
AWSKey.setBody(params["AWSAccessKeyId"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(AWSKey);

key.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"key\""));
key.setBody(params["key"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(key);

policy.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"policy\""));
policy.setBody(params["policy"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(policy);

signature.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"signature\""));
signature.setBody(params["signature"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(signature);

successRedirect.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"success_action_redirect\""));
successRedirect.setBody(params["success_action_redirect"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(successRedirect);

acl.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"acl\""));
acl.setBody(params["acl"].toString().toUtf8());
fileData->append(acl);

QNetworkRequest request(url);

QFile *file = new QFile(thread->fileName());
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

if (file->error() != QFile::NoError)
{
    qDebug("File Error");
    qDebug(file->errorString().toLatin1());
    return;
}


QFileInfo fi(file->fileName());

QString contentDisposition = "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fi.completeBaseName() + "." + fi.completeSuffix() + "\"";
qDebug(contentDisposition.toLatin1());

filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant(mime.mimeTypeForData(file).name()));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant(contentDisposition));
filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(fileData);
fileData->append(filePart);

QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, fileData);

connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(notifyUpload(qint64,qint64)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(notifyUploadFinish()));
```

Comment: Can you add your code: 1. how you get s3 parameters, 2. how you send to s3, 3. how you read the result

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant the code is, since the response is correct, but here goes the relevant parts:

The S3 parameters are from [CloudApp API documentation](https://github.com/cloudapp/api/blob/master/upload-file.md#request-to-upload) CloudApp API takes care of those parameters.

I send to S3 posting the values I got from the response to the upload request.

I updated the post with the code since I couldn't add it here because of the length.

Comment: Solved:
The problem was missing the "Accept" header for the GET request to the URL stated in the headers of the response to the POST request.
Adding the "Accept: application/json" header to the request to that URL
`http://my.cl.ly/items/s3?bucket=f.cl.ly&key=items0.0000002V1n29090S1u2f3j0t230.000000arch-tux.png&etag=%22b3e0682a5bdaa51eb2a342a4ea77aa0f%22`
in the example, turns the 302 to a 200 with the metadata for the uploaded file in the body.

Hope it helps.